# How to update a value in Realtime database by adding onto the value already there

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create an app which logs the steps for different days but I'm finding difficulty with updating the values.

Steps.kt

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    userreference.child("user_data/most_recent_per_day/Sun").setValue(currentStepsInt) //saves the stats for last saved day
    userreference.child("user_data/total_steps_by_day/Sun").setValue(+ currentStepsInt) //adds to total steps for Sat
```

What I'm trying to do is update the path ("user/data/total_steps_by_day/Sun") with the current data in that path + the currentStepsInt variable. What i actually get happening is it just sets the value as currentStepsInt only.

In firebase how would i get it to save whats already in that path and add a value on top of the value thats already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `ServerValue.increment` operation:

```
userreference.child("user_data/total_steps_by_day/Sun").setValue(ServerValue.increment(currentStepsInt))
```

Also see the reference documentation for [`ServerValue.increment()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue#increment).